# Personal Contact Form granular permissions

Tags: users, emails

I want to be able to set specific permissions by role for the use of the Personal Contact Form.

Searching drupal.org shows a few modules to work with Contact forms, but none do what I am looking to do, so I'm wondering if I'm overlooking something simple.

What I would like to do:

**Role A**

- Can have own Personal Contact form **BUT** it is *only* available to other Authenticated Users
- Can access and use Personal Contact form for any other user (Role A or Role B)

**Role B**

- Can have own Personal Contact form available to Anonymous **AND** Authenticated Users
- Can access and use Personal Contact form for any other user (Role A or Role B)

**Anonymous Users**

- Can only access Personal Contact Form for Role B Users, **NOT** Role A Users.

The idea is that **Role B** Users have the *privilege* of allowing the public / anonymous users to contact them via the Personal Contact Form, but all Authenticated Users should be able to contact each other using the form.

Should I do this with the Webform module? 
Or is there some permission setting for the Personal Contact Form I am missing?

I don't want it to be binary (either you have a Personal Contact Form or you don't), but I want some types of users to be able to access some other users Personal Contact Form.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using hook_form_alter.

Set up your roles,  then create a function using hook_form_alter that checks if it's building the contact form or not.   If building the contact form,  check the current user's role,  and either redirect to a 403 or allow it to go through.